# Adding what special characters make two email addresses same (Eg: adding . makes abc@d.com == ab.c@d.com)?

Tags: email, html-email, email-validation, email-client

I know that in Google if we use  abc@d.com ==  ab.c@d.com both are considered same. Similarly adding what characters make two email addresses same?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the recipients email provider, gmail do ignore '.' in the first part of the email as you say. But I wouldn't assume that hotmail, yahoo, corporates etc do the same.

Similarly, if you find another character that is ignored by one provider, I would be very careful about assuming other providers do the same.